# How to disable the Model driven (Reactive form) check boxes in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I am using angular4 Reactive forms with form builder

In my View component
I have bunch of check boxes so, I created form array,
After loads the page ,some check boxes are checked ,some are uncheked it depends on backed api data

```
 this.roleForm = this.fb.group({
permission: this.fb.array([])
    });
 this.permissionArray = <FormArray>this.roleForm.controls['permission'];
 this.permissionArray.push(this.fb.group({
            id: [this.newArray[p].group[k].permission.id],
            key: [this.newArray[p].group[k].permission.key],
            legend: [this.newArray[p].legend],
            ischecked: [this.newArray[p].group[k].permission.ischecked]
})

this.newArray[p].group[k].permission.ischecked is responce from bakend(there is no issues to get)
```

HTml

```
<form name='roleForm' [formGroup]="roleForm">
  <div formArrayName="permission">

  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let permission of roleForm.controls.permission.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
<input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="'ischecked'"
                                  [checked]="permission.value.ischecked"/>

</li>
</div>
</form>
```

I am getting checked and uncheked check boxes perfect with out issues,
My Problem is unable to disables the check boxes

If I tries like below, disabling is working but [checked] directive is not working

```
this.permissionArray.push(this.fb.group({
            id: [this.newArray[p].group[k].permission.id],
            key: [this.newArray[p].group[k].permission.key],
            legend: [this.newArray[p].legend],
            ischecked: [{value:this.newArray[p].group[k].permission.ischecked,  disabled: true}],

})
```

Please help me ,
Thanks in advance

Comment: when you want to disable the checkbox ?

Comment: on page loads only

Comment: disabled and you need to check that checkbox on page load

Comment: yes , checked depends on api responce, some should cheked, remaing uncheckd

Comment: and which one sholud be disabled ?

Comment: all checkboxes, this is view page there user can only view the page,what created, but not editable, so want to disable the field

Comment: Could you create a plunker. I'm not completely understanding your formarray, I see no iteration to push several form groups in your form array, and I guess `p` and `k` are supposed to be some indexes. Please create a minimal plunker that showcases the issue :)